# Why does 127.0.0.1 point to virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, virtualhost

I have a Virtual Host set up in apache to run CodeIgniter:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/CodeIgniter"
   ServerName codeigniter.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is, when I point my browser to 127.0.0.1, I'm getting the CodeIgniter home page instead of a list of the files in my root directory. Why is apache doing this?

Comment: Why would you expect 127.0.0.1 to show you a list of the files in your root directory? Do you expect it to act like a file browser, or did you have another virtualhost setup to do this for you via Apache?

Comment: Not a file browser, just a standard apache page where there is no index file included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've told it to direct all requests, regardless of what IP address they are from, to codeigniter. That's what the '*:80' part of your virtual host config is doing.

Try changing that to only use the IP address of the network adapter that you *want* to be listening for requests for the code igniter site.

Answer (score 1):

Unless told otherwise, Apache will direct traffic to the first VirtualHost specified. You could get around this by making a new Vhost for the root dir, which would obviously stop your CodeIgniter site from loading.